# Writing a shell script to email me if website says it is down for maintenance

Tags: shell, curl

I am Currently trying to make a shell script that will email me and other receipients if the website says it is down for maintenance. Curently i am trying to use curl and grep to pipe to a variable if grep see's the Phrase "Down for Maintenance" but when even when the website does not say that it it still outputs information. I want to make it so if the phrase exists it will make a vairiable true else it is false and just exits. Btw this is for a cronjob.

Here is what i have come up with so far. P.S sorry for being such a noob.

```
    ## Sends an email if the website is down for maintanance
    #RESPONSE = ''
    curl websiteaddress.com | grep "Down for Maintenance" | read RESPONSE
    if $RESPONSE
    then
    echo "Website is Down" | mail -s "Website is down for maintenance" email@address.com
    end else
    exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
curl websiteaddress.com | grep "Down for Maintenance" | read RESPONSE
if $RESPONSE
```

To:

```
curl websiteaddress.com | grep -q "Down for Maintenance"
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Website is Down" | mail -s "Website is down for maintenance" email@address.com
; fi
```

The `grep -q` tells grep to operate in "quiet mode", meaning it won't output anything. Instead it will exit with a return code of zero if a match was found, 1 if no match was found. the `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` checks the return code of grep.

Answer (score 0):

Your RESPONSE is initialized correctly, but in another process - because of the pipe.
In your calling script it is unkonwn.

If you need the RESPONSE, you can do the following:

```
read RESPONSE <<< $(curl websiteaddress.com | grep -q "Down for Maintenance")
```